How does a std::array of resizable containers/datatypes work?
I hope this is not a duplicate (link for an answer is also appreciated).
I have a C++ application, where I get a lot of Memory consumption over time. There is no leak by definition as all memory is still reachable (used valgrind for this). However my application seems to use more and more memory over time.
This led me to the general question how a std::array<std::vector<std::string>, 4> for example (or std::array<std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>>, 4> more specifically) does even work (compiler does not complain at all).
From my understanding a std::array needs to have a fixed size at compile time, so if one of the containers or contained data types resizes, how can I define a std::array from it in the first place?
Secondly: Is this something, that could be the cause for excessive memory usage. I usually keep everything local, so it should be properly destroyed during runtime (checked that multiple times), but maybe the resizing of a "normally fixed size container" could cause such effects?

Ain't size like size. An std::vector holds a pointer to data buffer. The sizeof(vector) doesn't include the allocated size of this buffer, but the size of this pointer. Reallocating the buffer doesn't change it. Meanwhile std::vector::capacity() gives the allocated number of elements and std::vector::size() doesn't refer to memory consumption at all.

std::array has fixed size, but std::vector which array contains has dynamic size. Note you have many dimensions (5), so small change in size of one of dimensions can have a great memory consumption. Without [mcve] it is impossible to help.

Memory fragmentation might also be a source of memory usage increase

I see, I have a lot to learn yet. Could memory fragmentation happen, when I allocate large data via a vector (for example image data via the cv::Mat object - some MB each - in a vector) and this vector goes out of scope at some point. Would it be possible, that not all data is properly released?

Fragmentation might happen with re-allocation (not necessary from the same object). It is not a leak though.

deeply nested std::vector is to be avoided. The big advantage of a std::vector is memory locality. Though, because the data is not stored directly within the std::vector object, already a std::vector<std::vector<T>> has the Ts scattered all around in memory. Instead of a nested vector you better use a flat vector with appropriate index transformation (or you are lucky and can use mdspan already)

Generally a good way to reduce your memory use is to deallocate it when it is no longer needed. Lots of idiots on SO say that you don't need to deallocate still reachable  memory. Maybe not always but in this case probably yes. Consider using a heap profiling tool. Masssif (snce you are already using Valgrind) would probably be a good start. Otherwise take a look at heaptrack and google perftools.

The size of an object never change. Which means that the size of an std::vector never change.
An std::vector does not actually contain its data. It allocates its data on the heap and will keep a pointer to its first element. That pointer will be part of the vector, not the data itself. Consequently, the data may be resized (i.e. new allocation on the heap) the vector won't change (the pointer will simply be updated to point to the new location).
With std::array<std::vector<T>, 4>, your array contains 4 vectors, and 4 is fixed and known at compile-time.
As for the endlessly growing memory usage, memory leaks are not the only possible candidates. For instance, if your program keeps feeding one (or several) of your vectors with new data, your memory consumption will grow as well.
We can't tell without seeing your code. If you haven't done it yet, I would advise you to step through your code with a debugger for example and monitor your containers sizes for example.

Thank you for the quick answer. The thing is, that the project is a multi threaded application for image processing, that takes about 15 minutes to compile. So there a multiple possible sources for this. I am still trying to identify possible guilty parts of the software. A Debugger is in use, but this was a part I was wondering about, if it could cause the problem. Thanks for helping, the answer solved some puzzlement from my side already. I will update the question, when I have narrowed it down a bit.

As for the second part: Usually the array of vectors go out of scope during the program use at certain specific points, so it should be cleared from my understanding, but the memory creep up persists across those points

@DaniMambo Do not change the questions, edits should only add more clarification/details, etc... If an edit is to invalidate already existing answers, you better ask a new separate question as a follow-up for example. For the vectors, I used them as an example but any container in your application can be the source cause, not necessarily those particular vectors :)

You can give each vector and each string a custom profiling allocator to generate a  memory consumption report; not sure the same could be done for openCV.
